# Selenium (python): How to access alerts?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, alert

During an interaction with a website via Selenium (Python) I get this popup window:
[image]

I want to check the checkbox and then click on the left button.

I tried accessing the popup window (about which I think is an alert) with

```
driver.switch_to.alert
```

However, this raises an `NoAlertPresentException`. As I did this step by step in a jupyter notebook, the popup is definitely already there (no timing problem).

Is this not an alert? How do I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share the url if it is public? It seems not an alert.

Comment: I think the webdriver alert control is exclusively for javascript alerts. Plenty of information found with a search of "javascript alert webdriver"

Comment: If this is a 2nd window, then would need to get window handles and switch to [1]

Comment: I'm not sure what it is yet, but I think it's not an alert as all of these I can detect: https://demo.automationtesting.in/Alerts.html

Comment: that prompt looks to be launched by the browser (outside the DOM) so Selenium probably can't interact with it.  (Prompt to install something?)  You'd need a robot-like class to interact with it.

Comment: It's definitely outside of the DOM - but so are alerts. I found two workarounds that I will post in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not figured out how to do this with Selenium, but I found two workarounds:

1: **Use pyautogui**

With [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can specify (x,y) coordinates on your screen where the mouse then clicks. This solution does not seem very stable as it depends on the screen size/resolution, the position of the browser and the browser itself.
I found two ways to make it a bit more reliable:

- Maximize the window (so that position does not play a role anymore)
- Use relative coordinates

2: **Use a Firefox profile**

In my case, the checkbox check could be saved in a firefox profile so that the popup does not appear anymore. A firefox profile can be created like this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles. This profile can then be used by selenium.